# nothing happen when i select the song to upload from my android app to firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I was creating an app for my semester project to upload songs from mobile storage to firebase's realtime database. app run correctly but when i select the songs to upload nothing happens and the app also does not crash. my main activity code is:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private boolean checkPermission = false;
Uri uri;
String songName, songUrl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    }
    //Create 2 function
    //onCreate option menu to initialize menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_menu , menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    //2nd function is onoption item selected (button sy reloated sari coding yaha hogi

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.nav_upload){
            if (validatePermission()){

               picksongs();
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    private void picksongs() {
        Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
        intent_upload.setType("audio/*");
        intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        startActivityForResult(intent_upload , 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 1){
            if (requestCode==RESULT_OK){
                uri = data.getData();
                Cursor mcursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri , null, null, null , null);
                int indexName = mcursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                songName = mcursor.getString(indexName);
                mcursor.close();
                uploadSong();
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void uploadSong() {
        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Songs").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.show();
        //upload files to firebase
        
        storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isComplete());
                Uri urlSong  =uriTask.getResult();
                songUrl = urlSong.toString();
                uploadtoDataBase();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot tasksnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0*tasksnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/tasksnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                int currentProgress = (int)progress;
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+ currentProgress+"%");
            }
        });
    }
private void uploadtoDataBase(){

        Song songobj = new Song(songName , songUrl);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Songs").push().setValue(songobj).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
    private boolean validatePermission(){
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
        //Dexter.withActivity(MainActivity.this)
        .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        checkPermission=true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                         checkPermission=false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
        return checkPermission;
    }
}
```

please help me to find where i made a mistake. but their is 1 problem startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)' is deprecated is that cause the problem? if yes then how can i solve this

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so I recommend you do some more troubleshooting and tell us the results. The best way to figure out what exactly is going on is to set a breakpoint on the first line of every method, running the code in a debugger, and then stepping through the code checking the values of each variable on each line. If you do this, which is the first line of your code that doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.